# Sort by key in map type column for each row in spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe in the below format:

```
Name   LD_Value
A37    Map(10 -> 0.20,5 -> 0.30,17 -> 0.25)
A39    Map(11 -> 0.40,6 -> 0.67,24 -> 0.45)
```

I need to sort based on keys in `LD_Value` column for each record in descending order.

Expected output:

```
Name   LD_Value
A37    Map(17 -> 0.25,10 -> 0.20,5 -> 0.30)
A39    Map(24 -> 0.45,11 -> 0.40,6 -> 0.67)
```

Is it possible to do sorting on map type column in spark dataframe?

I looked into spark higher-order functions but no luck.

Comment: You could define a UDF function to sort the maptype column. Take a look at this link: https://www.bmc.com/blogs/how-to-write-spark-udf-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first get the keys of the map using `map_keys` function, sort the array of keys then use `transform` to get the corresponding value for each key element from the original map, and finally update the map column by creating a new map from the two arrays using `map_from_arrays` function.

For **Spark 3+**, you can sort the array of keys in descending order by using a comparator function as the second argument to `array_sort` function :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "LD_Value_keys",
    F.expr("array_sort(map_keys(LD_Value), (x, y) -> case when x > y then -1 when x < y then 1 else 0 end)")
).withColumn("LD_Value_values", F.expr("transform(LD_Value_keys, x -> LD_Value[x])")) \
 .withColumn("LD_Value", F.map_from_arrays(F.col("LD_Value_keys"), F.col("LD_Value_values"))) \
 .drop("LD_Value_keys", "LD_Value_values")

df1.show() 

#+----+----------------------------------+
#|Name|LD_Value                          |
#+----+----------------------------------+
#|A37 |[17 -> 0.25, 10 -> 0.2, 5 -> 0.3] |
#|A39 |[24 -> 0.45, 11 -> 0.4, 6 -> 0.67]|
#+----+----------------------------------+
```

For **Spark < 3**, you can sort an array in descending order using this UDF:

```
# array_sort_udf (array, reverse): if reverse = True then desc
array_sort_udf = F.udf(lambda arr, r: sorted(arr, reverse=r), ArrayType(StringType()))
```

And use it like this:

```
df.withColumn("LD_Value_keys", array_sort_udf(F.map_keys(F.col("LD_Value")), F.lit(True)))
```